# What is the opposite of "star" (celebrity)?

Tags: word-request, antonyms

I want to know the opposite of the word "Star" ?

*Here star indicates a celebrity (people that appear in a movie).

Comment: Could you give a context in which you want to use the word?  In English, there are always many options, all with slightly different tones.  As it is, we can't be sure whether you mean an actor playing a minor part, someone who is simply unknown, or a modest and unassuming person.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Depending on where your universe ends, the opposite end of the spectrum could be an **extra** (if you are only thinking of the people that appear in a movie).  I think **nobody**, as has been repeatedly suggested, is the best colloquial term that the average person would consider the "opposite" of a star, but I wanted to bring up this possibility because I think it's interesting that the framing of the question could affect the answer.  It also indicates the looseness of the concept of "opposite"--there are many things that don't really have an absolutely clear opposite.

For example, if you think of a "star" as "a person to whom a great deal of positive attention is paid by the public", you could say that the opposite would be someone to whom a great deal of *negative* attention is paid (the "pariah" suggestion might be an approximate term here).  Or you could say it's a person to whom no positive attention is paid (the "nobody").  If you're thinking of a star as a person that appears in a movie or show that is the main focus of the show, then an "extra" would be a person in the movie or show who is furthest from being the main focus.

Comment: "Extra" seems good to me !

Comment: @user506555: Note that "extra" is very nearly jargon, and is unlikely to be used outside of film and television related contexts.  It's more of a job title than a descriptor.

Comment: @Kevin Puhleeze! "Extra" has been common usage in the progenetrix of those lesser arts at least since the 1880s.

Comment: @StoneyB: "progenetrix: *n.* Female progenitor."  Erm... which individual woman are you talking about?

Comment: @Kevin Great Mother Theatre.

Comment: I think @Kevin has a point at least about context mattering.  As long as the context of a movie is established, I think "extra" is a pretty generally known term.  It really matters what this usage is going to be embedded in.  It wouldn't really work if you're specifically referring to a rock star, for example.  There you might have roadie or even groupie if you wanted to keep it in-metaphor.  I still agree with the upvoters of Cookie Monster for the earliest instance of "nobody" as the most generally used "opposite" for the general concept of "star".

Answer (score 55):

If you walked up to me and asked what is the opposite of the words *star* and *celebrity*, my "knee-jerk reaction" answer would no doubt be [**nobody**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/nobody). The term *nobody* when used as a noun (notice that it's a noun in this case and not a pronoun) by most online dictionaries is defined as a person who is not important, but the word itself has come to mean more or less someone who is really just the epitome of not being successful or famous (the song *"The Nobodies"* by Marilyn Manson comes to mind all of a sudden). Here's a usage example:

> She's an internationally recognized superstar. And who am I? I'm **a nobody**! I'm just a plumber from New Jersey. No, we'll never be together! It's absolutely impossible! A superstar can only be married to another superstar.

Another expression that you might find interesting, apart from the ones that have already been mentioned such as [**nonentity**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/nonentity) and [**no-name**](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/no-name) which I personally like for their neutrality in meaning, would be [**no-hoper**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/no-hoper). *No-hoper* basically means someone who is a failure or someone who is doomed to failure right from the start. It's often used in a political context to refer to people who you're sure are never going to be able to build successful political careers and as a result become famous politicians. But its usage is not restricted only to politics. For example:

> You're **a real no-hoper**. You'll never achieve anything in life and you'll never become successful!

Note that *no-hoper* is mostly used in British English.

Comment: As a footnote, I think "nobody" is an excellent suggestion, but I can't recall ever seeing "no-hoper" before reading this answer.

Comment: @J.R. I think that's because, like me, you speak American English.  If you look at  [the Corpus of Global Web-Based English (GloWbE)](https://corpus.byu.edu/glowbe/?c=glowbe&q=63649964), you can see it's mainly used outside the U.S.  It does seem to be relatively current slang, judging by [Google Books Ngram Viewer](http://goo.gl/hcRVFv).

Comment: I heard it used quite recently, but it was a Brit who used it. He was referring to people who thought that they were unable to learn a foreign language as no-hopers.

Comment: "No-hoper" is indeed a familiar expression in Britain, but it only makes sense in this context if you're talking about people who are *trying* to be the thing you're talking about (a star). For example, "As a teacher at acting school, I might see one future star in my class every 5 years. All the other students are no-hopers", or "The singer of this band is a star in the making, but her bandmates are talentless no-hopers". The plumber from New Jersey modestly surprised to be dating a star wouldn't be a "no-hoper" unless they were terrible at plumbing.

Comment: You might consider doing a smaller number of more significant edits.  Small edits are okay sometimes, but if you want to change a lot, try to change more of it at one time.  We'd like to avoid bumping posts to the top of the front page over and over unnecessarily.

Comment: @snailplane Who are you talking to you? To me? I haven't been doing any changes to this post for the last 24 hours. But I do make a lot of small changes to my posts and I'll take your advice into consideration.

Comment: Yes, I'm leaving you a comment because this post has reached 17 revisions, and it seemed like this might be a bit of a pattern for your posts.  Thanks for responding :-)

Comment: @snailplane I guess this habit comes from the way I work with Word documents. I'm constantly pressing ctrl+s when I'm writing something in Word. Also, this personally happened to me on this website. I was once in the middle of editing one of my posts and I had made a lot of changes when someone decided to do an edit to it. I don't remember what exactly happened, I think they spotted a typo and figured that they could help me fix it, but as a result of such intervening I had lost all my changes. That's another reason why I always press *save* after even the smallest of edits.

Comment: "No-hoper" is not a good word for the opposite of celebrity, as it implies a basic lack of competence at anything.  There are a great many people who are quite competent and successful in their fields (which IMHO are generally worth far more to society than what most celebrities do to occupy their time), yet have no desire to be, or even a positive aversion to being, celebrities.

Comment: @jamesqf I just offered that as a possibility. In certain contexts, you might consider it the opposite of "celebrity" (someone who is successful).

Comment: No-hoper in Australian English is somewhat dated; it was very current two generations ago and bore a more scornful connotation than the British usage as I hear it. It wasn't used for general mediocrity but implied more a *wilful* mediocrity. It was a thoroughly judgmental, nasty and unkind term. That is, if you were a terrible plumber but devoted to your job and made a genuine effort, you might be called a "disaster", but never a "no-hoper". These days overtaken by "bludger" by the Murdoch press to pass judgment on anyone who is struggling to find work when there are four times as many ....

Comment: ... candidates as positions as is the wont of "normal" people who have "made it" (i.e. grew up in periods of much higher employment).

Answer (score 26):

Apart from [**nobody**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/nobody) as suggested, there are three possibilities for use.  The nicer term to use would be

**[Unknown](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/unknown)**

> ADJECTIVE
>
> 1.1 (of a performer or artist) not well known or famous.
>         *‘unknown artists of the avant-garde’*
>
> NOUN
>
> 1. An unknown person or thing.
>      *‘she is a relative unknown’*

Not as nice are

**[Commoner](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/commoner)**

> a common person, as distinguished from one with rank, status, etc.

or

**[Nonentity](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/nonentity)**

> A person or thing with no special or interesting qualities; an unimportant person or thing.

Comment: Interesting comment you made about "nobody." I wouldn't regard it as a rude term in the right context, but it certainly can be used disparagingly and therefore ought to be used with caution.

Comment: I like "unknown" - *nobody* does seem a bit disparaging, like "worthless" or "unimportant", but *unknown* just means "not known", and maybe "not known *yet*".

Comment: @stangdon But that is essentially what is being asked.  OP wants the opposite of 'star', not a middle, neutral word.

Comment: I was thinking about ["pleb"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/pleb?s=t) which would sort itself into commoner, but that has probably a worse ring to it.

Comment: Oh yes, @Arsenal.  That to me **would** be worse than commoner

Comment: "Extra " is preferable ?

Comment: I am confused.  If you mean for example, referring to another actor as an extra, then that would not be correct for what you are asking.  An extra is someone who [acts in the background of a scene being filmed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extra_(acting)).

Answer (score 7):

Some opposite words are:

> **No-Name**--*a person unknown in a particular profession.*
>
> **unimportant person**--*a person lacking in importance or significance.*
>
> **a zero**--*a worthless or contemptibly undistinguished person.*
>
> **a nobody**--*a person of no importance or authority.*
>
> **a nonentity**--*a person or thing with no special or interesting qualities; an unimportant person or thing.*

Comment: You need to cite your sources.

Comment: non-entity was my first thought.

Answer (score 5):

***[Nothing](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/nothing)*** (noun)  is often used in the sense you are referring to:

> someone of no value or importance:
>
> - ***He's a nothing***, a low-down, useless nobody.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Answer (score 5):

Without the proper context, it's hard to know exactly what is meant by the opposite of *star*, so I'll add another option that's not already listed:

**D-lister**

Ubrban dictionary describes [d-list celebrities](http://urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=d-list%20celebrities) as:

> A D-List celebrity is simply a person who is known simply through social networks, a person who has made a name for them selves through social networking sites such as Youtube, Facebook, Instagram, Twitter or what ever else is out there.
>
> D-List celebrities are not necessarily known for there talents but work put in, in areas such as video production, photography, game play or even just simple creativity and originality.

with the example dialogue:

> Person 1; "Is Nash Grier Even Actually Famous?"
>
> Person 2; "No!, Hes What You Call A D-Lister (d-list celebrities"

So a d-lister is someone who is a celebrity but certainly not a star.

Comment: I like this because it adds yet another context/universe.  In the universe of celebrities, this is the opposite end of the spectrum.  Very nice.

Answer (score 4):

There are

- stars (celebrated celebrities),
- has beens (they were celebrated once but now people have forgotten them), and
- never was (like you and me).

It is better to be a "has been" then a "never was."  Not everyone can be a star.

Comment: The first two options you suggested - stars, has beens - are plurals, but the third one (never was) looks singular to me. Is it? If so, what would its plural form look like?

Comment: @pt314 the unwashed masses, the hoi polloi, the peasantry, the proletariat, commoners, etc.  There are lots of words to describe us.

Comment: Sure, but what about that specific phrase? Would it be "never were"? "never weres"? "never wases"? Or did you mean to say that it's not possible to make that expression plural, and we have to pick something else if we are talking about multiple non-celebrities?

Answer (score 2):

The following is a completely non-standard use of the word, and I don't actually recommend using it unless you're in the company of native speakers who like to mess around with language and say silly things that nonetheless sort of make sense…

…but personally I would occasionally go with ***civilian***.

This term usually distinguishes a person from a member of a military organisation, but in some street dialects can be used in a sort of ironic sense to just mean anyone not part of whatever large group of folks you're presently talking about.

> Actor #1: Look at that fan over there, waiting for autographs.
>   Actor #2: Damn civvies.

Comment: annnnnnnd I'm astonished to actually find this usage in a dictionary ([#2 here](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/civilian))

Answer (score 2):

In sports, the "stars" of a team are complemented by "role players", "bench warmers", and "practice squad" members.

A "superstar" is famous enough that people who are unfamiliar with the sport may watch the team just to see the superstar play.  For example, Wilt Chamberlain, Magic Johnson, Larry Bird, Michael Jordan, or LeBron James.

A "star" is famous enough that most fans of the team are familiar with how the player helps the team.

A "role player" has one or two specific roles on a team.  Many fans of the team do not know who the role player is, or do not care what the role player does.  For example, Kurt Rambis.

A "bench warmer" rarely plays.  He is there in case better players get injured, or to learn the game so that he might be able to play in the future.

Many teams have a "practice squad".  The job of the practice squad is to simulate upcoming opponents, so that the first team can have realistic practices.  Many high-level women's teams practice against men.

A "replacement level" player is about as good as the best player who does not yet have a job in the league.  In men's sports leagues, "practice squad" players tend to be "replacement level" players.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers describe one who is not a star as a nobody, but the *opposite* of a star would be a

> [Pariah](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/pariah) (pəˈraɪ ə)
>
> noun
>
> 1. outcast.
> 2. any person or animal that is generally despised or avoided.

Comment: I wouldn't say this is the _opposite_; A celebrity can be a pariah, and many celebrities are considered pariahs in at least some community, but a celebrity can't be a *nobody*, which makes it the better choice as the natural opposite. Of course, if the intended meaning was "unpopular" then this would be on point.

Comment: This is a good example of how 'opposite' and 'antonym' aren't really rigorously defined concepts.  There are many different ways the meanings of two words can oppose one another, and depending how you interpret the idea of opposition, you can come up with different choices as "the" opposite of a word.

Comment: Roman Polanski would be both star and outcast.

Answer (score 1):

A Z-lister.

“A-list” is the list of the worlds most famous stars. “B-list” is someone not quite as famous, but still very well known. A Z-lister is someone trying to be famous and failing miserably.

The “extra” mentioned is different. That’s someone hired not as an actor, but because a human body is needed to fill a space or a function. As an extra in a TV series you can actually become recognisable if the same extra is used repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

An unknown "Average Joe" might seem to be the opposite of a star/celebrity but that is not the case.  Being an unknown is not the opposite of fame, it is merely the absence of fame.  The opposite of a star or celebrity would be someone infamous; i.e. famous for something bad.

Answer (score 1):

In Video Gaming Community I can think of those two :

**No-Name**

**Random**

Those hold a pejorative connotation though...

Answer (score 1):

There's loads of words you could use, depending on who's saying it:

**Civilian** is the word celebrities use to refer to non-celebrities

**(a) Nobody** is used by someone who likes to criticize others

**Just a regular guy/girl** sounds like a mouth-full of words but this is what most people would use, it's not derogatory like the previous example.

**Peon** is the word used by old-fashioned people like grandparents and villagers.

**Noob** is the word used by gamers.

**Broke Joke** is used by gold-diggers.

and finally...

**Diamond in the rough** is what a wanna-be celebrity would refer to themselves as.

Answer (score 0):

there is an idiom about terrible actors: couldn't act one's way out of a paper bag.